# Define many subset sequence in R

Tags: r, sequence, subset

Assume I have a dataframe called `data` which contains a column called `col` which contains numbers from 0 to 10'000.

How do I create the following subset with the function `subset` in R that can be called `sub`

- Numbers from 999 to 1200  AND
- Numbers from 1500 to 1599

Edit: I've tried a `sub<- subset(data, col >= 999 & col <= 1200 | col >= 1500& col <= 1599)` but I'm not sure I'm right doing so.

Comment: This is a very straight forward and basic question about subsetting data in `R`.  Can you share what you have tried and how it has and has not worked thus far?  Without that, this question will likely be closed.

Comment: Have you really searched SO for this topic?...

Comment: Sure I've tried sub<- subset(data, col >= 999 & col <= 1200 | col >= 1500& col <= 1599) but but I face 2 issues. I'm not sure the | is right and I'm not sure the way I'm doing is the proper one...

Comment: @all I'm sorry if this question seems too simple but I really did some research before to create this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your logic - you need to use parentheses to keep relevant statements together:

```
sub<- subset(data, (col >= 999 & col <= 1200) | (col >= 1500& col <= 1599))
```

Although to be honest, I think the way you did it will technically work.

Comment: `data <- data.frame(col = 1:10000, y = rnorm(10000))`; `sub1 <- subset(data, col >= 999 & col <= 1200 | col >= 1500 & col <= 1599)`; `sub2 <- subset(data, (col >= 999 & col <= 1200) | (col >= 1500 & col <= 1599))`; `all.equal(sub1, sub2)`.

Comment: Yes, as I said, the way he did it will also work. This is a better habit to get into.